# Why is my SSE matrix multiplication returning matrices with all 0s?

Tags: c++, matrix, sse

I'm writing an SSE-based Matrix class, and having some strange problems with the multiplication.  The strangest part is that it seemed to work before, but now it does not.  Any matrices that I multiply turn into all-zero matrices, even when multiplying two identities.

Matrices are 4x4, column-major, defined internally as `__m128 col0, col1, col2, col3;`.

Here's my multiply function:

```
inline static mat4 multiply(const mat4& lhs, const mat4& rhs)
{
    mat4 result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        result.col[i] = _mm_add_ps(
            _mm_add_ps(
                _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(rhs.col[i], rhs.col[i], _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0)), lhs.col0),
                _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(rhs.col[i], rhs.col[i], _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1)), lhs.col1)),
            _mm_add_ps(
                _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(rhs.col[i], rhs.col[i], _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2)), lhs.col2),
                _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(rhs.col[i], rhs.col[i], _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3)), lhs.col3)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The strangest thing is that it worked 2 days ago when I was working on it, and now it does not.  What the heck?

(edit: before anyone asks, they use a union, so `col[i] == coli`)

Here's an example:

```
mat4 C, D;
C.identity(); // mat4::identity() correctly sets the matrix to be an identity matrix.
D.identity();
C = mat4::multiply(C, D); // C now contains all 0's, when it should be an identity matrix.
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal, *complete* example for us to look at that reproduces the problem instead of an function out of context? (That's basically `int main()` to exercise it, some includes and a definition for mat4).

Comment: I could, but Matrix.h is 418 lines long...

Comment: That's why I said *minimal*, complete - reduce it to the simplest form possible to reproduce the problem in and you'll either find the solution yourself in the process or make it easy for others to help you. (Consider: I have a hunch about the problem that I'd like to test in a debugger. I'm not likely to invest the time to do that, but even if I did and my hunch didn't pan out 10 other people might end up duplicating the same effort just to get to the same starting point as you have. And did I mention you might find a solution in the process anyway?)

Comment: Well, you were absolutely right.  After removing some of the unused functions in the matrix class to make a minimal demo, it magically started to work again, despite not touching the multiply function in any way whatsoever.  Don't you just love it when code decides to act like witchcraft?

Comment: If your code acts like witchcraft it means that you are doing something wrong. Spend the time to understand the problem. It will help you in the long run. It might for example be uninitialized variables, that, when you change the code, can change location in memory, and thus value. Nothing is witchcraft in programming.

Comment: If you develop on Linux I highly recommended valgrind.

Comment: Since this is return-by-value, maybe you need to investigate the (default?) copy constructor.